# Storing Calculated values in an array from another method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to make a program that calculates factorials from 0 to 19 in one method and storing those values in an array in another method (if that makes sense). This is my code so far, it works but I want to take the values in method `long factorial (int number)` in the `void main(String[] args)` method. But I'm having trouble executing this. I've tried  changing `System.out.println (factorial(counter))` to `System.out.println (**x** [factorial(counter)])` but that failed. Sorry I'm new to programming and my English is not that good.

```
    for (int counter = 0; counter <= 20; counter++){

         System.out.println (factorial(counter));
```

Comment: Your code looks good. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to store results in the `x` array, then just assign on each iteration:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++){
    x[counter] = factorial(counter);
    System.out.println(x[counter]);
}
```

Comment: Realize that @nogard has modified `<=` to `<` in `for`, or you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.